# Stringify a tuple in python with dashes

Tags: python

I have a tuple I'd like to stringify to make into a redis key.

I've tried '-'.join but the output is not good --> dashes between every single letter from strings.  Can anyone suggest a better function than my string + '-' + string2... construction below?

Thanks!

```
matchkey = (mdate, season, aseries, homeclub, awayclub, court)
mk = mdate + '-' + season + '-' aseries + '-' homeclub + '-' awayclub + '-' court
```

Comment: Were you doing `'_'.join(mdate + season + aseries + homeclub + awayclub + court)` to get "_" between each letter or something else?

Comment: wanted dashes between terms, not between each letter.  For future stringifiers, here's what happens when you str() a tuple then attempt to join with dashes:  >>> mk1=str(matchkey)
>>> mk2='-'.join(mk1)
>>> print mk2
(-'-2-0-1-1---0-1---0-5-'-,- -2-2-,- -'-W-i-n-t-e-r- -C-l-u-b-'-,- -'-K-n-o-l-l-w-o-o-d-'-,- -2-)

Comment: ahh. I see. You're just doing it in the wrong order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
'-'.join(str(x) for x in matchkey)
```

Comment: `_` is conventionally used on variables you ignore

Comment: jamlak - what would you suggest as alternative to avoid that convention?

Comment: @ToddCurry +1 for correct answer, I would suggest for the general case `x` but it really doesn't matter eg. `el` works as well. Also you could just do `'-'.join(map(str, matchkey))`

Comment: yep, using `_` in oneliners is an arguably _bad_ habit of mine. However, on SO it is at least equally arguably a _good_ practice so that there is no confusion as in questions the original posters tend to use way too many one letter variables. :)

Comment: @Kimvais *"arguably a good practice"*, you are the only person I've ever heard argue that

Comment: hey, "present OP excluded" on that :)

Comment: @ToddCurry true, also you can accept an answer now (if you want)

Answer (score 5):

If all the items were strings you could simply

```
'-'.join(matchkey)
```

Since they aren't, you can use `map`

```
'-'.join(map(str, matchkey))
```

or a generator expression

```
'-'.join(str(x) for x in matchkey)
```

Comment: Helpful, gnibbler -- I will take a look at map to add to my repertoire